# USG Fiberock underlayment used for tile installation

Tags: flooring, tile, floor, subfloor, underlayment

I reinstalled the tiles in the laundry room and the installer used USG Fiberock, instead of Hardiebacker - as initially told me.

He’s telling me that USG Fiberock is good for laundry room.
But now I am going crazy, because I did not do research on this, and I see it is gyps based. I am going through manufacture instructions but wanted to check with some experts:

Do you know if this supports the weight of the washer and dryer?
Do you know if it has humidity barrier? It is screwed into the plywood.

I want to make sure that I don’t get the plywood affected by moisture or damaged by washer and drier pressure in time.

Thanks for your advices - or pointers to any document.

Comment: Says it's a water resistant underlayment suitable for tile, carpet, hardwood. Other than your tile installer lying about the brand used (and doing such a poor job that you are having to redo it?) I don't see any huge issue with it - it's not "drywall on the floor" just because it comes from USG. They make a lot of different products.

Comment: Seems like a little time spent reading [product literature](https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en/products/floors-tile/tile-prep/cement-board-backer-board/fiberock-underlayment.html) would be more productive than asking here. It specifically mentions moisture and wet areas.

Comment: To some, "hardibacker" is the "kleenex" of cementitious underlayments. Your installer may have been speaking generally and buying based on availability or cost.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting VtC, I don't see any request for a product recommendation, it's asking for details about a particular product's worthiness for a purpose. Of course, this info could probably be found on the manufacturer's site...

Comment: @FreeMan  I've seen a few VtC's  on posts like this and all I can figure out is it's because the OP didn't do his own research and just started out here so we'd do his research...

Comment: If that's the case, @JACK, then I'd hope people would spend the extra moment to type that into the "custom" reason box instead of just picking some random other reason. Of course, I may be expecting too much... :/

Comment: Thank you so mush for your answers and link. I am doing the research on this as well, but your expertise is helping me, since I don’t know much about this domain. If there is anything else that I should read, please let me know, any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Folks, also sorry if I did not pick up the right categories. This is out of my domain.

Answer (score 1):

Direct quote from https://www.usg.com/content/usgcom/en/products/floors-tile/tile-prep/cement-board-backer-board/fiberock-underlayment.html Indicates that the material is suitable to the purpose.

> A water-resistant underlayment that delivers support for hardwood,
> ceramic tile, carpeting and more in homes or light commercial
> building. Fiberock® Brand Underlayment represents a new era in
> substrate performance for wet or dry areas. It has an integral
> water-resistant composition that offers durability, superior
> performance and exceptional tile bond that is not susceptible to the
> same warping often found in traditional wood underlayment. MAIN
> FEATURES
>
> Fiberock® Brand Underlayment provides a smooth, flat surface that
> resists swelling and contains none of the resins, adhesives or
> solvents that can stain floor covering materials. It also offers
> greater resistance to indentation than other underlayment products and
> can be used in all areas — wet or dry — regardless of the flooring
> material chosen.